# Print delay in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, queue

My stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 looks like this:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
AS
BEGIN
   print 'start'
   waitfor delay '00:02:00'
   print 'end'
END
GO
```

as intended, in output I want to get:

```
start
```

And then after 2 minutes:

```
end
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `print` you can use `raiserror with nowait` and severity level 0.

```
raiserror('Start', 0, 0) with nowait
waitfor delay '00:02:00'
raiserror('End', 0, 0) with nowait
```

Severity level below 11 is not treated as exception (in Sql Management Studio it looks like usual print), and `with nowait` option sends messages immediately to the client.

Comment: working the same as example above, only after 2 minutes prints both messages

Comment: @IgO make sure you haven't missed `with nowait`. It **should** send message immediately. At least, it does so at my server.

Comment: no, i used your code, and still not working properly

Comment: @IgO I believe you just haven't switched to the 'messages' tab in the output. Try this while your query is still working, and you will see the 'Start' message